# Raspberry Pi Zero as read write mass storage

Tags: module, raspberry-pi-zero

I am trying to setup a Raspberry Pi Zero as a mass storage with `dwc2` and `g_mass_storage` (using the last Raspbian image available).
I created the data storage file  with `dd`, made it a FAT32 fs with `mkdosfs`.
I looked for a lot of things. I spent some time to understand that options should be passed in `/etc/modprobe.d/g_mass_storage.conf`
It is finally seen in ubuntu. My problem is : it is in read only mode.

I tried to set the `ro` option to `y` or `n` without any impact on the behaviour. I changed permissions on the file (777), it changed nothing.
here is the current content of my `/etc/modprobe.d/g_mass_storage.conf` file :

```
options g_mass_storage file=/piusb.bin stall=0 removable=y ro=n
```

here is the of `dmesg` from the ubuntu :

```
[Today and now]usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 28 using ehci-pci
[  +0,299994] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  +0,959969] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  +0,187918] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 29 using ehci-pci
[  +0,113925] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=a4a5
[  +0,000007] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=0
[  +0,000004] usb 1-1.2: Product: Mass Storage Gadget
[  +0,000003] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.19.118+ with 20980000.usb
[  +0,001467] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0,000246] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 0525 pid a4a5: 10000
[  +0,000283] scsi host9: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  +1,009528] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Linux    File-Stor Gadget 0419 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  +0,001079] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[  +0,001699] sd 9:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[  +0,001211] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] 67108864 512-byte logical blocks: (34.4 GB/32.0 GiB)
[  +0,000672] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is on
[  +0,000016] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 0f 00 80 00
[  +0,000740] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  +0,005478]  sde:
[  +0,002735] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

What to do to get a read/write mass storage ?

Comment: I don't know if it change something but I am powering the pi zero with the "usb" port, which means it boots when I plug it to the computer.

Comment: I tested using external power supply and it only remove the `errors -71`

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem. I had a similar problem with the module `g_acm_ms` on Raspberry Pi Zero W. If you configure the module in `/etc/modprobe.d/`, then the system ignores the parameter `ro=0`. Perhaps this is due to the order of initialization of kernel modules. I got around this by adding the module to the blacklist and writing the initialization in `/etc/rc.local`. Thus, I managed to get an emulation of a read/write mass storage.

All steps:

1. Create and format the file:

   ```
   # dd bs=1M if=/dev/zero of="/piusb.bin" count=2048
   # mkdosfs "/piusb.bin"
   ```
2. Add `modules-load=dwc2,g_acm_ms` to end of `/boot/cmdline.txt` (after `rootwait`)
3. Add the string `dtoverlay=dwc2` in `/boot/config.txt`
4. Prevent module initialization at startup:

   ```
   $ echo "blacklist g_acm_ms" | sudo tee -a "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-g_acm_ms.conf"
   ```
5. Add initialization in `/etc/rc.local` above `exit 0`:

   ```
   # nano /etc/rc.local
   ```
6. Add string:

   ```
   /sbin/modprobe file=/piusb.bin removable=y ro=0 stall=0
   ```
7. Reboot system:

   ```
   # reboot -h
   ```

P.S.: If you don't want to use USB for console output, you can use `g_mass_storage` instead of `g_acm_ms`.